# Add css class to dynamic button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating dynamic buttons using jQuery, is there a way to add CSS class to it while creating it, what I want to avoid is to write another line of JavaScript to add CSS class to it, unless there is no other way.
Find the code snippet below,

```
 $.each(data, function (index, value) {
       var button =  $('<button/>', {
              text: value, 
              id: 'btn_' + index,
              click: function () { MNS.ButtonClick(this) }
       });
       $('#MyDiv').append(button);
 });
```

do we have something like this,

```
  $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        var button =  $('<button/>', {
               text: value, 
               id: 'btn_' + index,
               **css:'Myclass'**
               click: function () { MNS.ButtonClick(this) }
        });
        $('#MyDiv').append(button);
  });
```

Comment: `"class" : "myClass"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `class` in constructor

```
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
    var button =  $('<button/>', {
        "class" : "myClass" //Set the CSS to be add 
    });
});
```

*OR*, use the method `addClass` on created object

```
button.addClass('myClass')
```

Answer (score 2):

use below code . use `class` as parameter.

```
var button =  $('<button/>', {
        class : "className",
        click: function () { MNS.ButtonClick(this) }
});
```